# Continuous integration for automation tools

Tags: selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, geb

I am trying to find out as to which CI (Continuous Integration) tools are available for automation tools such as QTP, Selenium webdriver, Waitr and GEB.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside QTP...there are multiple CI tools (Open source and paid) which are compatible with Selenium Webdriver & GEB & Watir..will focus on what we have used...

***Jenkins*** (Open source)

I have personally used it and found very flexible with numerous plugins available as per flavor of repository and post build actions.

Best part is this is compatible with Selenium Webdriver & Watir.

***Gradle*** (Open source)

Since we are talking about Geb (groovy language), i would recommend to use Gradle tool. Since it has awesome compatibility and easy to configure.

Not that Jenkins can't be used for Geb, i would prefer to stick with Gradle when it comes to groovy.

There are other open source tools(hudson etc) and as well as paid tools(bamboo,teamcity..etc). It all depends on what all parameters to be addressed as per project or company in your build integration...to select a tool.

I would suggest come up with ur own requirements and then start evaluating any tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for which automation tool is better for CI?
If That is your question, I would suggest Thucydides framework with selenium webdriver. This framework has a great support for CI with abilities to define stories, steps and others. 
http://www.thucydides.info/

QTP is a costly tool but automation is faster and efficient with it. We don't have support like the Thucydides framework for CI in QTP but it can be used nonetheless. QTP also supports windows application testing as against selenium which only supports Web browser testing (Testing of web applications run in a browser)

Hope this helps you.